# Rails 4.2 migration error but no rollback

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, rollback

I have a migration with many remove_column.

I start it, but there is an error :

> -- remove_column(:responses, :text_fr)
>      -> 0.5544s
>   -- remove_column(:responses, :text_en)
>      -> 0.2906s
>   -- remove_column(:topics, :text_fr)
>   rake aborted!
>   StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
>   Mysql2::Error: Can't DROP 'text_fr'; check that column/key exists

It's my fault because I don't give the good name of column.

But my problem is : **there is no automatic rollback !**

I have fix the name of column in migration file, but now it's not working because `text_fr` don't exist in `responses` table...

I remember before, when an error occur, there was a rollback as if migration had not occurred...

So how enable auto-rollback of migrations?

I'm using mysql2 gem.

Comment: @emaillenin there is no solution since for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MySQL does not [support transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/687006/184184), implement `up` and `down` methods for your migrations.

Comment: Why rails don't do it automaticly (when it's possible)? Like "remove_column" => "add_column" ...

Comment: yes, you should do `rake db:rollback` to do that