# Revert a migration without changing the schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

The last migration that I ran was not completed because of errors. It can't be reverted with `rails db:rollback` (nor with `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=xxx`) because this commands tries to drop databases that were not created (or that I destroyed to try to solve the issue).

Is there a way to switch to `down` the status of the last migration, and that it doesn't try to affect the database?

The following worked: editing the migration file, renaming the `change` method to `up`, adding an empty `down` method, and running the `rails db:rollback` again. Nonetheless, I was wondering if there was a better solution.

(Note that this question is not about [cleaning up the failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686852/rolling-back-a-failed-rails-migration) but just about switching the last migration status to `down`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a `schema_migrations` table in your database with a single `version` column which will have the numerical portion of your migration. Simply delete that row.

Comment: That's definitely a better solution. I guess that there is no direct command to do it then.